# Importing Router in Angular2 app

Tags: angular, typescript1.5

```
///<reference path='../../../typings/angular2/angular2'/>

import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import { Router } from 'angular/router';
import {Login} from '../login/login';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
})
@View({
  template: '<login></login>'
})
  // Component controller
export class FreshairAppComponent {
  constructor(router:Router) {
    router
        .config(['/login',Login,'login'])
      .then(()=>router.navigate('login'));
  }
}

bootstrap(FreshairAppComponent);
```

Typescript(1.5) output:

> /usr/bin/tsc --sourcemap /home/larry/Projects/FreshAir2/src/components  /app/app.ts --target es5 --m commonjs --emitDecoratorMetadata --outdir /home/larry/Projects/FreshAir2/public/js
>   /home/larry/Projects/FreshAir2/src/components/app/app.ts(4,24): error TS2307: Cannot find external module 'angular/router'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: change angular to angular2.

`import { Router } from 'angular2/router';`

Comment: Duh!  Old age is taking its toll.

Comment: Great example of using the router [in Angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/angular-class/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/app/components/app.ts).